# LineStrings not showing. Only the labels do

Tags: xml, kml, google-earth

I'm trying to generate a KML file using XSLT, which would show all the bus routes from a city. Everything seems to work fine, except I don't see the routes lines, but when I click on a bus number, it'll show me the label associated to it. I am not sure why it does that. Here is a part of my generated file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><kml xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

<Style id="couleur-metrobus">
<LineStyle>
<color>8DC740</color>
<width>2</width>
<gx:physicalWidth>2</gx:physicalWidth>
</LineStyle>
<LabelStyle>
<color>000000</color>
</LabelStyle>
</Style>

<Placemark>
<name>800</name>
<description>metrobus</description>
<styleUrl>#couleur-metrobus</styleUrl>
<LineString>
<tessellate>1</tessellate>
<coordinates>-71.33077615,46.75183033,0.00000000 -71.33102882,46.75166296,0.00000000 -71.33121051,46.75156178,0.00000000 -71.3313392,46.75150417,0.00000000 -71.33150566,46.75143369,0.00000000 -71.33162664,46.75138512,0.00000000 -71.33176994,46.7513409,0.00000000 -71.33188982,46.75130584,0.00000000 -71.33200995,46.75128698,0.00000000 -71.33216289,46.75127417,0.00000000 -71.33234357,46.75127735,0.00000000 -71.33252189,46.75129765,0.00000000 -71.33265202,46.75133359,0.00000000 -71.33281652,46.75139087,0.00000000 -71.33296673,46.75145545,0.00000000 -71.33316196,46.75155389,0.00000000 -71.33335097,46.75167306,0.00000000 -71.33351895,46.7517861,0.00000000 -71.33367549,46.7519217,0.00000000 -71.33384179,46.75209592,0.00000000 -71.33394076,46.75223285,0.00000000 -71.33398829,46.75234406,0.00000000 -71.33401072,46.75244016,0.00000000 -71.33401992,46.75252736,0.00000000 -71.33400714,46.75263271,0.00000000 -71.3339646,46.75275987,0.00000000 -71.33390861,46.75286374,0.00000000 -71.33378242,46.75299871,0.00000000 -71.33361323,46.75314658,0.00000000 -71.33309968,46.75354257,0.00000000 -71.33264796,46.75387423,0.00000000 -71.33244147,46.75398009,0.00000000 -71.33229916,46.75408908,0.00000000 -71.33212106,46.75425412,0.00000000 -71.33207973,46.7542904,0.00000000 -71.33197066,46.75443244,0.00000000 -71.33192328,46.75450116,0.00000000 -71.33184251,46.7546115,0.00000000 -71.33175218,46.75469583,0.00000000 -71.33166794,46.75475042,0.00000000 -71.33156263,46.75479707,0.00000000 -71.33140481,46.7548342,0.00000000 -71.33128603,46.75485575,0.00000000 -71.33106492,46.75486276,0.00000000 -71.3308039,46.75482867,0.00000000 -71.33053806,46.7548207,0.00000000 -71.33040976,46.75481983,0.00000000 -71.33032473,46.75482315,0.00000000 -71.33023448,46.7548274,0.00000000 -71.33018218,46.75483138,0.00000000 -71.32997312,46.75485629,0.00000000 -71.32973151,46.75489223,0.00000000 -71.32937692,46.75498656,0.00000000 -71.32933523,46.75499946,0.00000000 -71.32909447,46.75509117,0.00000000 -71.32885667,46.75520535,0.00000000 -71.3286774,46.75529481,0.00000000 -71.32852054,46.75539401,0.00000000 -71.32835602,46.75550676,0.00000000 -71.32698996,46.75639739,0.00000000 -71.32684225,46.75649652,0.00000000 -71.32503538,46.75767011,0.00000000 -71.32472323,46.75788828,0.00000000 -71.32428422,46.75820092,0.00000000 -71.32404037,46.75834842,0.00000000 -71.32402352,46.75835934,0.00000000 -71.32402352,46.75835934,0.00000000 -71.32392242,46.75842574,0.00000000 -71.32381992,46.75848586,0.00000000 -71.32360332,46.75861786,0.00000000 -71.32278665,46.75914644,0.00000000 -71.32204263,46.7596331,0.00000000 -71.32204263,46.7596331,0.00000000 -71.32197524,46.75967766,0.00000000 -71.32158225,46.75991889,0.00000000 -71.32094736,46.76035168,0.00000000 -71.32080996,46.76044173,0.00000000 -71.32070103,46.76050999,0.00000000 -71.32059465,46.76057373,0.00000000 -71.32045459,46.7606611,0.00000000 -71.31996329,46.76098129,0.00000000 -71.31886076,46.76165673,0.00000000 -71.31612794,46.7633496,0.00000000 -71.31612794,46.7633496,0.00000000 -71.31594117,46.76346519,0.00000000 -71.31424296,46.76458295,0.00000000 -71.31148316,46.76641624,0.00000000 -71.31139497,46.76647175,0.00000000 -71.31126647,46.76654643,0.00000000 -71.31018973,46.76729717,0.00000000 -71.31018973,46.76729717,0.00000000 -71.31014179,46.76733079,0.00000000 -71.30998733,46.76742095,0.00000000 -71.30986531,46.76749109,0.00000000 -71.30746269,46.76906356,0.00000000 -71.30746269,46.76906356,0.00000000 -71.30743677,46.76908084,0.00000000 -71.30735117,46.76913542,0.00000000 -71.30726558,46.7691909,0.00000000 -71.30685609,46.76947628,0.00000000 -71.30671712,46.76955193,0.00000000 -71.30664055,46.76959745,0.00000000 -71.3055139,46.7703467,0.00000000 -71.30543606,46.77039493,0.00000000 -71.3051622,46.77055699,0.00000000 -71.30503903,46.77063882,0.00000000 -71.30473933,46.77082446,0.00000000 -71.30278253,46.77210581,0.00000000 -71.30241401,46.7723315,0.00000000 -71.30221049,46.77246968,0.00000000 -71.30201226,46.77261231,0.00000000 -71.30119895,46.77313081,0.00000000 -71.30119895,46.77313081,0.00000000 -71.30085002,46.77335366,0.00000000 -71.30075635,46.7733948,0.00000000 -71.30016301,46.77382539,0.00000000 -71.29984045,46.77397338,0.00000000 -71.29969592,46.77402837,0.00000000 -71.29955251,46.77407076,0.00000000 -71.29945452,46.77408584,0.00000000 -71.2993616,46.77408919,0.00000000 -71.29920694,46.77407947,0.00000000 -71.29890738,46.77401139,0.00000000 -71.29845339,46.77386072,0.00000000 -71.29769581,46.7733685,0.00000000 -71.29644126,46.77247219,0.00000000 -71.29620971,46.77230916,0.00000000 -71.29620971,46.77230916,0.00000000 -71.29455184,46.77114125,0.00000000 -71.29408764,46.77082779,0.00000000 -71.29352559,46.77044844,0.00000000 -71.29338397,46.77034507,0.00000000 -71.29326745,46.77025681,0.00000000 -71.29324629,46.77024256,0.00000000 -71.29247386,46.76971352,0.00000000 -71.29247386,46.76971352,0.00000000 -71.29238789,46.76965474,0.00000000 -71.29171808,46.76915737,0.00000000 -71.29147311,46.76897014,0.00000000 -71.29119256,46.76876696,0.00000000 -71.29106823,46.76868145,0.00000000 -71.29080643,46.76850693,0.00000000 -71.29019518,46.76807303,0.00000000 -71.29019518,46.76807303,0.00000000 -71.28994645,46.76789661,0.00000000 -71.28945749,46.76749784,0.00000000 -71.28931601,46.76740256,0.00000000 -71.28888633,46.76711763,0.00000000 -71.28882681,46.76707666,0.00000000 -71.28868132,46.766976,0.00000000 -71.28823423,46.76720219,0.00000000 -71.28666709,46.76801636,0.00000000 -71.28634469,46.76817512,0.00000000 -71.28634469,46.76817512,0.00000000 -71.2861809,46.76825631,0.00000000 -71.286099,46.76829646,0.00000000 -71.2849216,46.76890461,0.00000000 -71.28413286,46.76931935,0.00000000 -71.28385335,46.76945711,0.00000000 -71.2837702,46.76950177,0.00000000 -71.2837702,46.76950177,0.00000000 -71.28364417,46.7695692,0.00000000 -71.28256173,46.77013799,0.00000000 -71.28179088,46.77052471,0.00000000 -71.28136444,46.77073454,0.00000000 -71.28124098,46.77079926,0.00000000 -71.28070832,46.77108808,0.00000000 -71.28058222,46.77115102,0.00000000 -71.28058222,46.77115102,0.00000000 -71.28035213,46.77126684,0.00000000 -71.28026888,46.7713052,0.00000000 -71.28018955,46.77134262,0.00000000 -71.27968255,46.77159618,0.00000000 -71.27904064,46.77193792,0.00000000 -71.27858685,46.77215962,0.00000000 -71.27846341,46.77222524,0.00000000 -71.27720131,46.77287436,0.00000000 -71.27720131,46.77287436,0.00000000 -71.27567793,46.77365839,0.00000000 -71.2754166,46.77378881,0.00000000 -71.27527369,46.77386715,0.00000000 -71.27520352,46.77390451,0.00000000 -71.27012865,46.77651447,0.00000000 -71.27025729,46.77662786,0.00000000 -71.27029771,46.77670765,0.00000000 -71.27032188,46.77674977,0.00000000 -71.27036179,46.77679359,0.00000000 -71.27073037,46.77711138,0.00000000 -71.26999089,46.7775068,0.00000000 -71.26988267,46.77763168,0.00000000 -71.26986036,46.77772,0.00000000 -71.26985695,46.77784867,0.00000000 -71.26987257,46.77793403,0.00000000 -71.26989989,46.77801302,0.00000000 -71.26993201,46.77806138,0.00000000 -71.26998902,46.77811048,0.00000000 -71.27006339,46.77818285,0.00000000 -71.27094353,46.77892543,0.00000000 -71.27102571,46.77899505,0.00000000 -71.27021217,46.77943326,0.00000000 -71.27021217,46.77943326,0.00000000 -71.27001984,46.77953711,0.00000000 -71.2696556,46.77970869,0.00000000 -71.2693302,46.77994119,0.00000000 -71.2664151,46.78151354,0.00000000 -71.26625779,46.78159466,0.00000000 -71.26603528,46.78169601,0.00000000 -71.26597794,46.78171619,0.00000000 -71.2656579,46.78177411,0.00000000 -71.26538854,46.7818038,0.00000000 -71.26524454,46.78180836,0.00000000 -71.26495224,46.78179052,0.00000000 -71.26482675,46.78180755,0.00000000 -71.26467279,46.78184817,0.00000000 -71.26454252,46.78189672,0.00000000 -71.26441042,46.78200196,0.00000000 -71.26434983,46.78225516,0.00000000 -71.26425347,46.78257158,0.00000000 -71.26416414,46.78273771,0.00000000 -71.26405975,46.78285716,0.00000000 -71.26395109,46.78295235,0.00000000 -71.263799,46.78303344,0.00000000 -71.26363135,46.78312542,0.00000000 -71.26342192,46.78322578,0.00000000 -71.26279854,46.78350613,0.00000000 -71.26268532,46.78355726,0.00000000 -71.2625578,46.78361569,0.00000000 -71.2625578,46.78361569,0.00000000 -71.26160269,46.78405478,0.00000000 -71.26105741,46.78439487,0.00000000 -71.26009224,46.78495907,0.00000000 -71.25979229,46.78514279,0.00000000 -71.25864323,46.78585753,0.00000000 -71.25784466,46.78635043,0.00000000 -71.25728612,46.7866825,0.00000000 -71.25660312,46.78710535,0.00000000 -71.25622798,46.78734713,0.00000000 -71.25573313,46.78764548,0.00000000 -71.25570584,46.78766096,0.00000000 -71.25570584,46.78766096,0.00000000 -71.25564866,46.78769282,0.00000000 -71.25345343,46.78909815,0.00000000 -71.25292079,46.78941203,0.00000000 -71.25222166,46.78981067,0.00000000 -71.25147567,46.79023121,0.00000000 -71.25068681,46.79067811,0.00000000 -71.24988749,46.79112777,0.00000000 -71.24910256,46.79157644,0.00000000 -71.24910256,46.79157644,0.00000000 -71.24901939,46.79162377,0.00000000 -71.24824996,46.79205793,0.00000000 -71.24746888,46.79250296,0.00000000 -71.24702579,46.79276225,0.00000000 -71.24638369,46.7931236,0.00000000 -71.24572875,46.79350392,0.00000000 -71.24469824,46.79410259,0.00000000 -71.24398834,46.79448866,0.00000000 -71.24329398,46.79486292,0.00000000 -71.24329398,46.79486292,0.00000000 -71.24309374,46.79497128,0.00000000 -71.24213288,46.79549481,0.00000000 -71.24176098,46.79569514,0.00000000 -71.24148924,46.79584355,0.00000000 -71.24141643,46.7958836,0.00000000 -71.24082999,46.79620138,0.00000000 -71.24006023,46.79662109,0.00000000 -71.23942311,46.79696977,0.00000000 -71.23942311,46.79696977,0.00000000 -71.23931258,46.79702986,0.00000000 -71.23809842,46.79771603,0.00000000 -71.23757842,46.79800907,0.00000000 -71.23709494,46.79829107,0.00000000 -71.23698969,46.79835473,0.00000000 -71.23607061,46.79887614,0.00000000 -71.23526075,46.79933926,0.00000000 -71.23432737,46.79987154,0.00000000 -71.23432737,46.79987154,0.00000000 -71.23418178,46.79995524,0.00000000 -71.23307161,46.80059121,0.00000000 -71.23218894,46.80109796,0.00000000 -71.23132312,46.8015938,0.00000000 -71.23072617,46.80191789,0.00000000 -71.22990732,46.80240082,0.00000000 -71.22990732,46.80240082,0.00000000 -71.22973705,46.80250087,0.00000000 -71.22844223,46.80324772,0.00000000 -71.22833023,46.80329792,0.00000000 -71.22789859,46.80354447,0.00000000 -71.22664944,46.80428111,0.00000000 -71.22639333,46.80442938,0.00000000 -71.22639333,46.80442938,0.00000000 -71.22550149,46.80494603,0.00000000 -71.22325654,46.80617386,0.00000000 -71.2231009,46.80619463,0.00000000 -71.22304861,46.80620306,0.00000000 -71.22209923,46.80673265,0.00000000 -71.22136521,46.80720149,0.00000000 -71.22136521,46.80720149,0.00000000 -71.22126387,46.807266,0.00000000 -71.22046268,46.80771007,0.00000000 -71.219732,46.80803764,0.00000000 -71.21942856,46.8081772,0.00000000 -71.21891767,46.80838282,0.00000000 -71.21847325,46.80856194,0.00000000 -71.2179833,46.80876564,0.00000000 -71.21727182,46.80906248,0.00000000 -71.21727182,46.80906248,0.00000000 -71.21675581,46.80927803,0.00000000 -71.2165082,46.80937944,0.00000000 -71.21508781,46.80997129,0.00000000 -71.21482496,46.81001072,0.00000000 -71.21398562,46.81035152,0.00000000 -71.21374577,46.81044568,0.00000000 -71.21391294,46.81060208,0.00000000 -71.21436618,46.81098789,0.00000000 -71.21513265,46.81167403,0.00000000 -71.21551229,46.81204141,0.00000000 -71.21581876,46.81232558,0.00000000 -71.21581876,46.81232558,0.00000000 -71.21592091,46.8124203,0.00000000 -71.21631128,46.81280561,0.00000000 -71.21666422,46.81313536,0.00000000 -71.21675924,46.81308709,0.00000000 -71.2168477,46.81303795,0.00000000 -71.21692277,46.81296821,0.00000000 -71.21704099,46.812891,0.00000000 -71.21724547,46.81279706,0.00000000 -71.21739951,46.81275291,0.00000000 -71.2175315,46.81272599,0.00000000 -71.21762058,46.81272363,0.00000000 -71.21812919,46.81273754,0.00000000 -71.21828262,46.81274557,0.00000000 -71.21994918,46.812727,0.00000000 -71.21994918,46.812727,0.00000000 -71.22009461,46.81272519,0.00000000 -71.22027539,46.81272135,0.00000000 -71.22061067,46.81270755,0.00000000 -71.22076766,46.81268857,0.00000000 -71.22101833,46.81261951,0.00000000 -71.22202875,46.81233425,0.00000000 -71.22222202,46.81228445,0.00000000 -71.22280191,46.81214135,0.00000000 -71.22301066,46.81217152,0.00000000 -71.22313525,46.81227689,0.00000000 -71.22330049,46.81248186,0.00000000 -71.22354417,46.81277181,0.00000000 -71.22367087,46.81293654,0.00000000 -71.22367087,46.81293654,0.00000000 -71.22384159,46.81315947,0.00000000 -71.22420536,46.81360879,0.00000000 -71.22411078,46.81359139,0.00000000 -71.22403893,46.81360804,0.00000000 -71.22398028,46.8136318,0.00000000 -71.22388947,46.81369985,0.00000000 -71.22310929,46.81395758,0.00000000 -71.22141956,46.81449993,0.00000000 -71.22099291,46.81463937,0.00000000 -71.22099291,46.81463937,0.00000000 -71.2209068,46.8146678,0.00000000 -71.2204045,46.81483379,0.00000000 -71.21966459,46.81506696,0.00000000 -71.21896643,46.81528636,0.00000000 -71.21881076,46.81530713,0.00000000 -71.21867119,46.81535569,0.00000000 -71.2185737,46.81541478,0.00000000 -71.21826713,46.81551926,0.00000000 -71.21803761,46.81560347,0.00000000 -71.21794632,46.81563643,0.00000000 -71.21794632,46.81563643,0.00000000 -71.21777024,46.81569871,0.00000000 -71.21720451,46.81592536,0.00000000 -71.21676339,46.81606217,0.00000000 -71.2165575,46.81614983,0.00000000 -71.21629678,46.81625312,0.00000000 -71.21601365,46.81634665,0.00000000 -71.21551882,46.81648559,0.00000000 -71.2153804,46.81652244,0.00000000 -71.21535945,46.81662243,0.00000000 -71.21537832,46.8166619,0.00000000 -71.21547235,46.81683494,0.00000000 -71.21555174,46.81708994,0.00000000 -71.21556233,46.8172959,0.00000000 -71.21556233,46.8172959,0.00000000 -71.21556408,46.81732917,0.00000000 -71.21554992,46.81744711,0.00000000 -71.21552506,46.81754893,0.00000000 -71.21530376,46.81874773,0.00000000 -71.21516465,46.81932617,0.00000000 -71.21512335,46.81957203,0.00000000 -71.21513844,46.81972127,0.00000000 -71.21537301,46.82041163,0.00000000 -71.2154548,46.82055056,0.00000000 -71.21550427,46.82062492,0.00000000 -71.21573536,46.82075573,0.00000000 -71.21587392,46.82092579,0.00000000 -71.21681675,46.82195088,0.00000000 -71.21725443,46.82243844,0.00000000 -71.21725443,46.82243844,0.00000000 -71.21732227,46.82251358,0.00000000 -71.21732756,46.82251715,0.00000000 -71.21735094,46.82259977,0.00000000 -71.21760899,46.82278618,0.00000000 -71.21811759,46.82308706,0.00000000 -71.21830769,46.82319023,0.00000000 -71.21839754,46.82324454,0.00000000 -71.21851546,46.82334006,0.00000000 -71.21885301,46.82358984,0.00000000 -71.2193248,46.82398002,0.00000000 -71.21966583,46.82429365,0.00000000 -71.21989447,46.82453422,0.00000000 -71.22025008,46.82485945,0.00000000 -71.22030279,46.82488071,0.00000000 -71.22030279,46.82488071,0.00000000 -71.22041745,46.82492767,0.00000000 -71.22068447,46.82519498,0.00000000 -71.22147502,46.82589621,0.00000000 -71.22313172,46.82735936,0.00000000 -71.22358651,46.82774783,0.00000000 -71.22402957,46.82813997,0.00000000 -71.22508116,46.82904375,0.00000000 -71.22508116,46.82904375,0.00000000 -71.2253676,46.82929023,0.00000000 -71.22549111,46.82931194,0.00000000 -71.22536042,46.82953588,0.00000000 -71.22501844,46.83042329,0.00000000 -71.22498949,46.8306097,0.00000000 -71.22467174,46.83144837,0.00000000 -71.22437805,46.83222392,0.00000000 -71.22434511,46.8323087,0.00000000 -71.22434511,46.8323087,0.00000000 -71.22411336,46.83291472,0.00000000 -71.22393529,46.83332068,0.00000000 -71.22380618,46.83337098,0.00000000 -71.2236707,46.83362913,0.00000000 -71.2236283,46.83379133,0.00000000 -71.22341118,46.83441346,0.00000000 -71.2233543,46.83457125,0.00000000 -71.22315477,46.83513748,0.00000000 -71.22305958,46.83537019,0.00000000 -71.22312371,46.83546065,0.00000000 -71.22304635,46.83565456,0.00000000 -71.22278383,46.83621669,0.00000000 -71.22278383,46.83621669,0.00000000 -71.22275579,46.83627625,0.00000000 -71.2224499,46.83692861,0.00000000 -71.22214699,46.83760795,0.00000000 -71.22186437,46.83823678,0.00000000 -71.22158331,46.83878643,0.00000000 -71.22133478,46.83931878,0.00000000 -71.22133478,46.83931878,0.00000000 -71.22129274,46.83940991,0.00000000 -71.2209947,46.84006313,0.00000000 -71.22095902,46.84014072,0.00000000 -71.22088372,46.84029413,0.00000000 -71.22069133,46.84071098,0.00000000 -71.22066565,46.84075162,0.00000000 -71.2206198,46.84085267,0.00000000 -71.22055047,46.84096196,0.00000000 -71.22049971,46.84108823,0.00000000 -71.22032147,46.84148519,0.00000000 -71.22018087,46.84175597,0.00000000 -71.22010455,46.84193188,0.00000000 -71.22010074,46.8419409,0.00000000 -71.22010074,46.8419409,0.00000000 -71.22005867,46.84203023,0.00000000 -71.21967926,46.84277841,0.00000000 -71.219533,46.84301863,0.00000000 -71.21930216,46.84340513,0.00000000 -71.21875928,46.84428478,0.00000000 -71.21847714,46.8446599,0.00000000 -71.21825849,46.84487989,0.00000000 -71.217984,46.8451416,0.00000000 -71.21781832,46.84530278,0.00000000 -71.21767431,46.84541793,0.00000000 -71.2174625,46.8455614,0.00000000 -71.21639344,46.8463166,0.00000000 -71.21601502,46.84655287,0.00000000 -71.21591116,46.84663089,0.00000000 -71.21618652,46.84682888,0.00000000 -71.21618652,46.84682888,0.00000000 -71.21659823,46.84712409,0.00000000 -71.21697397,46.84737543,0.00000000 -71.21703398,46.84745152,0.00000000 -71.21712704,46.8475472,0.00000000 -71.21725144,46.84763279,0.00000000 -71.21732809,46.84767819,0.00000000 -71.2174984,46.84756827,0.00000000 -71.2178065,46.84736841,0.00000000 -71.21639344,46.8463166,0.00000000 -71.21558181,46.84572522,0.00000000 -71.21463788,46.84632757,0.00000000 -71.21420752,46.84660285,0.00000000 -71.21291488,46.84741158,0.00000000 -71.21208666,46.84794392,0.00000000 -71.21148464,46.84832911,0.00000000 -71.21122393,46.8486447,0.00000000 -71.21082725,46.84918965,0.00000000 -71.2104549,46.84969036,0.00000000 -71.2104549,46.84969036,0.00000000 -71.21040078,46.84976266,0.00000000 -71.21021099,46.84998785,0.00000000 -71.20990893,46.85015166,0.00000000 -71.20919826,46.85045474,0.00000000 -71.20755128,46.85115495,0.00000000 -71.20669051,46.85151383,0.00000000 -71.20593298,46.85184597,0.00000000 -71.20544125,46.85204782,0.00000000 -71.20544125,46.85204782,0.00000000 -71.20515039,46.85216746,0.00000000 -71.2043731,46.85249432,0.00000000 -71.20396785,46.85269203,0.00000000 -71.20324581,46.85303293,0.00000000 -71.2026157,46.8532842,0.00000000 -71.20154939,46.85367489,0.00000000 -71.2009609,46.8539007,0.00000000 -71.20090229,46.85393165,0.00000000 -71.20090099,46.85393255,0.00000000 -71.20090099,46.85393255,0.00000000 -71.20079814,46.85399076,0.00000000 -71.2005821,46.85411713,0.00000000 -71.20016213,46.85439499,0.00000000 -71.19984506,46.85461914,0.00000000 -71.1997096,46.85469014,0.00000000 -71.19949057,46.85478954,0.00000000 -71.19929127,46.85489331,0.00000000 -71.19914528,46.85496168,0.00000000 -71.19884308,46.85511916,0.00000000 -71.19855097,46.85524689,0.00000000 -71.19800125,46.85543107,0.00000000 -71.19770445,46.85560111,0.00000000 -71.19734879,46.85588486,0.00000000 -71.19712996,46.85610121,0.00000000 -71.19683681,46.85635129,0.00000000 -71.19655375,46.85657073,0.00000000 -71.19626968,46.85681356,0.00000000 -71.19604817,46.85702632,0.00000000 -71.19604817,46.85702632,0.00000000 -71.19600542,46.85706706,0.00000000 -71.19532241,46.85769736,0.00000000 -71.1948814,46.85807608,0.00000000 -71.19444767,46.85841068,0.00000000 -71.19400713,46.85872552,0.00000000 -71.19385221,46.85881463,0.00000000 -71.19350698,46.85899485,0.00000000 -71.19315425,46.8592039,0.00000000 -71.19278553,46.85939325,0.00000000 -71.19255183,46.85947563,0.00000000 -71.19239008,46.85954409,0.00000000 -71.19239008,46.85954409,0.00000000 -71.19195441,46.85972935,0.00000000 -71.19169349,46.85983708,0.00000000 -71.19098481,46.86010855,0.00000000 -71.19080234,46.86019782,0.00000000 -71.19026962,46.86048711,0.00000000 -71.19026962,46.86048711,0.00000000 -71.19018497,46.8605335,0.00000000 -71.18926606,46.86118678,0.00000000 -71.18844398,46.86172071,0.00000000 -71.18802377,46.86198952,0.00000000 -71.18746069,46.86236805,0.00000000 -71.18718836,46.86261169,0.00000000 -71.18718836,46.86261169,0.00000000 -71.18716631,46.86263072,0.00000000 -71.18652539,46.86318064,0.00000000 -71.18573992,46.86391675,0.00000000 -71.18502698,46.86458135,0.00000000 -71.18486772,46.86474423,0.00000000 -71.18459203,46.86503466,0.00000000 -71.18423176,46.86537868,0.00000000 -71.18375936,46.86577644,0.00000000 -71.18325914,46.86625623,0.00000000 -71.18325914,46.86625623,0.00000000 -71.18307901,46.86642913,0.00000000 -71.18285962,46.86671293,0.00000000 -71.18269018,46.86690106,0.00000000 -71.18249016,46.86705789,0.00000000 -71.18227786,46.86717701,0.00000000 -71.18174954,46.86740776,0.00000000 -71.18156449,46.86750333,0.00000000 -71.18048669,46.86805671,0.00000000 -71.18027323,46.86818843,0.00000000 -71.1800989,46.86830282,0.00000000 -71.1800989,46.86830282,0.00000000 -71.1800859,46.86831189,0.00000000 -71.17978808,46.86851518,0.00000000 -71.17961923,46.86864843,0.00000000 -71.17951162,46.86874803,0.00000000 -71.17931868,46.86894709,0.00000000 -71.17912195,46.86915787,0.00000000 -71.17897565,46.86931078,0.00000000 -71.17886149,46.86941221,0.00000000 -71.17866549,46.86957711,0.00000000 -71.17834328,46.86982372,0.00000000 -71.17801529,46.87013243,0.00000000 -71.17779999,46.87032713,0.00000000 -71.17763099,46.87044958,0.00000000 -71.17731521,46.87068625,0.00000000 -71.17707194,46.87084873,0.00000000 -71.17694437,46.87092685,0.00000000 -71.17675271,46.87102064,0.00000000 -71.17657286,46.87111437,0.00000000 -71.17637201,46.87120732,0.00000000 -71.17621276,46.87127033,0.00000000 -71.17607463,46.87134312,0.00000000 -71.17607463,46.87134312,0.00000000 -71.17587783,46.87144594,0.00000000 -71.17567917,46.87160905,0.00000000 -71.17524133,46.87194719,0.00000000 -71.17503613,46.87211214,0.00000000 -71.1747746,46.87228371,0.00000000 -71.17473297,46.87231094,0.00000000 -71.17473297,46.87231094,0.00000000 -71.17444025,46.87250609,0.00000000 -71.17400584,46.87280552,0.00000000 -71.17362575,46.87304257,0.00000000 -71.17330956,46.87324954,0.00000000 -71.1729998,46.87344658,0.00000000 -71.1728572,46.87358327,0.00000000 -71.17253525,46.87385505,0.00000000 -71.1723731,46.87400174,0.00000000 -71.17191432,46.87445245,0.00000000 -71.17173391,46.87460824,0.00000000 -71.17158561,46.87470897,0.00000000 -71.17148677,46.87477792,0.00000000 -71.17148677,46.87477792,0.00000000 -71.17145035,46.87480333,0.00000000 -71.17130573,46.87488334,0.00000000 -71.17112983,46.87497974,0.00000000 -71.16977828,46.87580002,0.00000000 -71.16943088,46.87603146,0.00000000 -71.16921113,46.87619018,0.00000000 -71.16879696,46.87653895,0.00000000 -71.16856603,46.87674812,0.00000000 -71.16815661,46.87705728,0.00000000 -71.16811378,46.87709442,0.00000000 -71.16811378,46.87709442,0.00000000 -71.16800215,46.87719133,0.00000000 -71.16770661,46.87737478,0.00000000 -71.16700972,46.87788443,0.00000000 -71.16692827,46.87798207,0.00000000 -71.16664354,46.8782968,0.00000000 -71.16623305,46.87873371,0.00000000 -71.1660396,46.87889856,0.00000000 -71.16590054,46.87900553,0.00000000 -71.16549322,46.87927509,0.00000000 -71.16485507,46.87965844,0.00000000 -71.16445767,46.87988206,0.00000000 -71.16409698,46.88010456,0.00000000 -71.16383563,46.8802959,0.00000000 -71.16351455,46.88053886,0.00000000 -71.16338062,46.88063679,0.00000000 -71.16317296,46.88082062,0.00000000 -71.16300961,46.8809808,0.00000000 -71.16287595,46.88110123,0.00000000 -71.16279398,46.88115658,0.00000000 -71.16279398,46.88115658,0.00000000 -71.16267427,46.88123824,0.00000000 -71.16244525,46.8813925,0.00000000 -71.16199392,46.88171358,0.00000000 -71.16175732,46.88189218,0.00000000 -71.16146484,46.88211518,0.00000000 -71.16133904,46.88223465,0.00000000 -71.16109666,46.88247715,0.00000000 -71.16099547,46.8825713,0.00000000 -71.16080948,46.88270462,0.00000000 -71.16065844,46.88279905,0.00000000 -71.16053333,46.88286815,0.00000000 -71.16020844,46.88301666,0.00000000 -71.15992938,46.88315771,0.00000000 -71.15978862,46.88323499,0.00000000 -71.15964277,46.88332489,0.00000000 -71.15949186,46.88343102,0.00000000 -71.15937492,46.88352436,0.00000000 -71.15930324,46.88356435,0.00000000 -71.15917876,46.88368562,0.00000000 -71.1587436,46.88404438,0.00000000 -71.15863085,46.88415928,0.00000000 -71.15866949,46.88420764,0.00000000 -71.15878662,46.88434371,0.00000000 -71.15878662,46.88434371,0.00000000 -71.1588026,46.88436251,0.00000000 -71.15894618,46.88462257,0.00000000 -71.15900174,46.88476619,0.00000000 -71.15904951,46.88491706,0.00000000 -71.15908606,46.88511566,0.00000000 -71.159136,46.88544374,0.00000000 -71.15924888,46.88630313,0.00000000 -71.15960347,46.88868241,0.00000000 -71.15960347,46.88868241,0.00000000 -71.15961637,46.8887714,0.00000000 -71.15864087,46.88883729,0.00000000 -71.15826192,46.88886106,0.00000000 -71.15747275,46.88892587,0.00000000 -71.15650915,46.88899977,0.00000000 -71.15571336,46.88906011,0.00000000 -71.15571336,46.88906011,0.00000000 -71.15553637,46.88907372,0.00000000 -71.15455431,46.88914051,0.00000000 -71.15362874,46.88921237,0.00000000 -71.15311868,46.88924587,0.00000000 -71.1530151,46.88925276,0.00000000 -71.15290484,46.88925069,0.00000000 -71.15283258,46.889243,0.00000000 -71.15260241,46.88920024,0.00000000 -71.15238634,46.8891286,0.00000000 -71.15219121,46.88905324,0.00000000 -71.15208018,46.88920321,0.00000000 -71.15194818,46.889356,0.00000000 -71.15183147,46.88947092,0.00000000 -71.15170185,46.8896039,0.00000000 -71.15166288,46.88963651,0.00000000 -71.15122348,46.88997907,0.00000000 -71.15078945,46.89033149,0.00000000 -71.15031604,46.89068414,0.00000000 -71.14991566,46.89099858,0.00000000 -71.1497804,46.89109921,0.00000000 -71.1496831,46.89119242,0.00000000 -71.14956173,46.89135684,0.00000000 -71.14952698,46.89141372,0.00000000 </coordinates>
</LineString>
</Placemark>
```

Anyone has an idea of why I can't see my routes?

Here's an output example from Google Earth:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to display the KML?

Comment: Google Earth 7.1.2.2041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my LineStyle colors. They were HTML hexadecimal colors (RRGGBB). So I guess it didn't recognized the color, so it just didn't show any. To solve this, I converted them to KML colors (AABBGGRR), in which AA represents the alpha code, which is optional for HTML colors.